# JSF - How to migrate URLs by intercepting and redirecting potential 404 errors?

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces, ocpsoft-rewrite

When migrating websites often dead URLs happen since old website used different URL structure or technology. Correct 301 "permanent" redirect is important for SEO friendly migrations.

**Example:**

Old page `https://example.com/product/coca-cola-bottle.html` moved in our JSF project to `https://example.com/p/coca-cola-1-l/1000`

**Concept**

We will save those mappings in our database and add them to our JSF application.

If an URL is requested that is not valid or rewritten we want to check the current requested URL if it exists in our database and redirect to the new target.

**Some Ideas?**

- Create a custom exception handler and redirect if resource was not found
- Override navigation handler to handle it *before* exception handler
- Use *@WebFilter* with *DispatcherType.ERROR* and *404* error code check
- Use OCPSoft rewrite solution. Not sure how to do this without loading all mappings into configuration. I prefer dynamic (lazy) approach.

Right now i implemented *@WebFilter* version using an injected bean to lookup the mapping.

Comment: To be honest, I guess build a custom web filter for this is the best approach. And it should be fairly easy to do. Not sure if you really should try to detect 404 errors though. Why not matching the incoming request again the rewrite rules you have in your DB and then redirect the user accordingly.

Comment: You could also inject the bean into your rewrite config and look it up dynamically in the rewrite ConfigurationProvider as well. You would probably need to add the "rewrite-integration-cdi" module to support @Inject on your configuration provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by including the `rewrite-integration-cdi` module:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/integration/cdi.asciidoc

Then create a CDI bean/Java class that can access your database.

Inject an instance of that class into your Rewrite `ConfigurationProvider`, then use it to build / create your Rewrite rules.

Here is an example of both `@Inject`ing beans into your ConfigurationProvider, and also defining custom HTTP operations:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/showcase/rest-ws/src/main/java/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/showcase/rest/RestRewriteConfiguration.java

Depending on how dynamic you want your database lookups to be, you could either preload them at startup time (when the Config is built), or load & cache them inside the Request/Response lifecycle itself using a custom `HttpCondition` and `HttpOperation:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/api-servlet/src/main/java/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/servlet/config/HttpCondition.java

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/api-servlet/src/main/java/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/servlet/config/HttpOperation.java

Then use those operations in your `ConfigurationProvider` to perform the database operations. Essentially you will do something like this, but check the database to see if the requested URL is a ‘known/stored’ redirect:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/851ccbabb8b6248c66589076fa67cb0ec07b3132/impl-servlet-tests/src/test/java/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/servlet/config/HttpRequestParameterTestProvider.java#L45

And then use an custom `HttpOperation` to perform the actions you want to take.

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/851ccbabb8b6248c66589076fa67cb0ec07b3132/config-servlet/src/test/java/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/servlet/config/JoinBindingConfigurationProvider.java#L48

You could also technically just use a `Condition` that matches all requests, and an `HttpOperation` That only takes action if there is a database entry.

All that said, this sounds more complicated than it is, but there’s no good example I can find to link to that does exactly what you want, so I’m trying to piece it together.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply and condition and operation look interesting. Since not all incoming URLs are known, which i did not thought about before asking it will lead to `Condition that matches all requests` where i also think a `@WebFilter` as @chkal mentioned is the better solution right now.

Comment: Fair enough! You can always just use an `Operation` without a `Condition` and it will match everything :) But I tend to agree a simple filter might be the easiest option with least overhead and "magic".